# Name mismatch when using Fortran shared library

Tags: c, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I managed to successfully compile a shared library using IFORT that contains some .obj files (i.e. dependencies) compiled by Visual Studio C.

When trying to use this shared library in a Fortran program it fails saying `Example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TEST_mp_EXECUTE referenced in function MAIN__`.

When I use the tool `dumpbin.exe` I can see that function `execute` is in the shared library. Any idea why this mismatch of names that is making the compilation of the Fortran program to fail?

Content of file `Test.c`:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int execute(void);

int execute(void)
{
    return 2 + 3;
}
```

File `Test.c` successfully compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio C as follows (the result is an object file named `Test.obj`):

```
cl.exe Test.c /FoTest.obj
```

Content of file `Test.f90`:

```
MODULE Test

    USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_int
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTERFACE

        INTEGER(c_int) FUNCTION execute() BIND(C, name = "execute")
            USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_int
        END FUNCTION

    END INTERFACE

END MODULE
```

File `Test.f90` successfully compiled with IFORT as follows (the result is a shared library named `Test_dll.dll` along with its header file named `Test_dll.lib`, and a Fortran module file named `test.mod`):

```
ifort.exe Test.obj /Qm64 /LD /FeTest_dll.dll
```

Content of file `Example.f90`:

```
PROGRAM Example

    USE test

    state = execute()

END PROGRAM
```

Now, when trying to compile file `Example.f90` as `ifort.exe Example.f90 Test_dll.lib` it fails saying `Example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TEST_mp_EXECUTE referenced in function MAIN__`. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, we need more details, but note that `test_execute` is not `TEST_mp_EXECUTE`.  This latter would be expected to be a procedure `execute` in the module `test`, not a procedure called `test_execute`.

Comment: @francescalus: you are right; I have edited the question to reflect your comment but also because this is what is happening in reality (somehow, I copied and pasted this wrongly in the original question).

Comment: But we still need the [mcve]. Just changing the name of the function is not enough. The MCVE includes the commands used for the compilation and any other necessary configuration we have to use.

Comment: @VladimirF: I have added the question to include a MCVE.

Comment: Have a look with e.g. depends in the dll / lib file to see which name is stored theer .

Comment: Which version of the compiler?  It appears to be a little confused and so a later version, if available, would be a good place to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have two sources that compile to a test.obj - the Fortran and the C. Also, the cl command you showed tries to generate an executable. Here's how to do it right:

```
cl /c /MD /Foctest.obj test.c
ifort /dll test.f90 ctest.obj
ifort example.f90 test.lib
```

I added /MD to the C compile to get a compatible set of run-time libraries. This generated the executable without errors.

Comment: Thanks; it worked! I needed to include `DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: execute` (in file `Test.f90`) for the shared library to be used properly though. Now, I am trying to build a static library but when using it it fails saying `Example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TEST_mp_EXECUTE referenced in function MAIN__` (despite having the `!DEC$ ...` declaration now). Do you have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: It is incorrect to add DLLEXPORT of execute in the Fortran source, since execute is a C routine and you already have it exported from C. Not that this does anything for a static library. I suspect that the cause is the same as I wrote before - overwriting object files. Perhaps you can show us what you are using for sources and commands now?

Comment: Of course @Steve. The command used to build the static library is `lib.exe ctest.obj test.obj /OUT:test_static.lib` which runs successfully. The command used to build a Fortran program (`example.f90`) that uses the static library `test_static.lib` is `ifort.exe example.f90 test_static.lib` which fails with the aforementioned error.